# Image with all colors

Tags: java, image, algorithm

I'm trying to write an algorithm to satisfy [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22144/images-with-all-colors). I've double, triple, and quadruple checked my logic, but I think I'm missing something obvious. This program should group each color next to similar colors, but it produces something more akin to noise.

This is sort of what I expect (taken from a similar answer): [image: Expected]

And this is what I'm actually getting: [image: Experimental]

```
public class AllColors extends JFrame {

    private static final int WIDTH = 256;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 128;
    private static long TOTAL_ITERATIONS = (WIDTH * HEIGHT) * 185000;
    private static int VALUES_PER_CHANNEL =32;
    private static int CHANNEL_DELTA = 256/VALUES_PER_CHANNEL;
    static BufferedImage image;

    private static final int SCALE = 5;

    static int[][] kernel =     { { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                                  { 0, 2, 3, 2, 0 },
                                  { 1, 3, 0, 3, 1 },
                                  { 0, 2, 3, 2, 0 },
                                  { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 } };

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AllColors f = new AllColors();
    f.setTitle("All Colors");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

    init();
    //gui stuff
    JPanel p = new JPanel(){
    @Override
     public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.scale(SCALE, SCALE);
          g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
     }
    };

    p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    f.add(p);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);


    group(p);
}
//makes an image of all colors
private static void init() {
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

for(int r = 0; r < VALUES_PER_CHANNEL; r+= 1){
    for(int g = 0; g < VALUES_PER_CHANNEL; g+= 1){
        for(int b = 0; b < VALUES_PER_CHANNEL; b+= 1){
            x++;
            if(x % WIDTH == 0){
                y++;
                x = 0;
            }
            if(y >= HEIGHT)
                return;
            image.setRGB(x, y, new     Color(r*CHANNEL_DELTA,g*CHANNEL_DELTA,b*CHANNEL_DELTA).getRGB());
        }
    }
}
}
//group together similar pixels
private static void group(JPanel panel){
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(long i = 0; i < TOTAL_ITERATIONS; i++){
        Point first = new Point(rand.nextInt(WIDTH), rand.nextInt(HEIGHT));
        Point second = new Point(rand.nextInt(WIDTH), rand.nextInt(HEIGHT));

        trySwitch(first, second);

        if(i % (WIDTH * HEIGHT) == 0){
            System.out.println(i / (WIDTH * HEIGHT));
            panel.repaint();
        }
    }
}
private static void swap(Point first, Point second){
    int temp = image.getRGB(second.x, second.y);
    image.setRGB(second.x, second.y, image.getRGB(first.x, first.y));
    image.setRGB(first.x, first.y, temp);
}
//get how similar the neighbors are
private static int getNeighborDelta(int imageX, int imageY){
    Color center = new Color(image.getRGB(imageX, imageY));
    int sum = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < kernel[0].length; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < kernel.length; y++)
        {
            int weight = kernel[x][y];
            if (weight <= 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            int xOffset = x - (kernel[0].length / 2);
            int yOffset = y - (kernel.length / 2);
            try{
            sum += getDistance(new Color(image.getRGB(imageX + xOffset, imageY + yOffset)), center) * weight;
            }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                //if out of image
            }
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
//switches if the neighbors will be more similar
private static void trySwitch(Point first, Point second){
    double firstDistance = getNeighborDelta(first.x, first.y);
    swap(first, second);
    double secondDistance = getNeighborDelta(first.x, first.y);
    if(secondDistance > firstDistance)
        swap(first, second);
}
//get similarity between colors
private static double getDistance(Color one, Color two){
    int r = Math.abs(two.getRed() - one.getRed());
    int g = Math.abs(two.getGreen() - one.getGreen());
    int b = Math.abs(two.getBlue() - one.getBlue());
    return r + g + b;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to (1) briefly summarize the problem statement here, (2) perhaps add a high-level description of your code, or some comments, and (3) include some screenshots of desired versus actual results.

Comment: I can't see how your result is highly different from the sample. Your sample looks like noise to me also.

Comment: Well, the point of the challenge is that the image is created using all 15 bit colors. In my post, I linked to the original challenge. My examples are different because my second is clearly noise, but the first is noise that has been grouped together by similarity in color. Yes, it's quite similar, but the first is much prettier.

Comment: I don't see any "grouped together by similarity in color" in the first image.  What I see is a bunch of circles of one color overlaid on top of each other.  This is what you would see if you magnified a small section of your output and blurred the individual pixels into each other.